The @ symbol does not escape properly in razor views in VS2022 17.10.1
In a razor view (.cshtml) of an ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC web application, I have this markup and code:
@{
  var DropDownList = new Syncfusion.EJ2.DropDowns.DropDownList() { ... }
}
<e-grid-column ... edit="new {@params = DropDownList }" ...></e-grid-column>

This example uses the Syncfusion grid component and is based on the official documentation BUT the question is not restricted to Syncfusion.
The assignment:
edit="new {@params = DropDownList }"

causes the following build error(s) in VS 2022 17.10.1:

Interestingly, it builds when converted to an explicit razor expression:
edit="@(new {@params = DropDownList })"

Also, I reverted to VS 2022 17.9.7 and it builds fine as it always had.
No other code and/or package modification/update has taken place; I just loaded the project and tried to start debugging. Only VS has been updated since the last time.
Has anyone else experienced this?
Any idea about what might have changed in VS/Core/C#/MSBuild?
UPDATE
It seems anonymous object in razor view is just a case of a general problem with the @ symbol not escaping properly. More information can be found in this reported VS issue.
I believe the OP's title should be updated to reflect the real problem at hand. Furthermore, I am not sure if this can be answered here since it is clearly a bug that needs to be addressed.

What matters is the type of the edit="" attribute in that <e-grid-column> tag-helper: different tag-helper attributes can accept different types of special Razor syntax. For example, asp-for="" accepts an Expression<Func<...>> for model-binding, but that won't work for a simple String attribute - let alone a (non-tag-helper) HTML attribute.

Also, Razor has special handling for @ (as it's used to delimit different kinds of runs of a Razor document) - while C# also uses @ to allow escaping keywords. Razor lets you use @@ to escape it though, so what happens if you do edit="new { @@params = DropDownList }"?

@Dai As said in OP, it used to build okay and still builds okay in VS 2022 17.9.7. Build fails in VS 2022 17.10.1. <e-grid-column>'s edit property expects params. In C#, using a double @ (like @@) doesn't serve any specific purpose for escaping property names or identifiers. The @ symbol is used to escape reserved keywords or identifiers, but adding an extra @ doesn't change the meaning or add additional escaping functionality. But thanks for the comments, maybe it is a problem with the @ symbol not working as it should (and the question needs to be rephrased).

What happens if you disable the "new" Razor editor and use the old version? (it's under Tools > Options, but I don't know exactly which page because they change it almost every release).

@Dai Have updated the OP. I am staying with 17.9.7 until the bug is resolved. Thanks for your feedback.
